# Azure AppService: Accessing logs from all scaled machines

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Given an Azure AppService deployment, running a WebAPI application that has scaled out to 6 instances.

Our WebAPI application writes diagnostic logs using NLog and a File appender.  Is there a way to inspect these log files via the Azure Portal or Kudu?

I note that Kudu can access the file system in a sandbox ... but when the application has scaled out to 6 instances it appears that the sandbox is only viewing the 1st instance.

Is there any way to access the log files on any of the other 5 instances?

Comment: Actually App Service uses a shared storage for files so all instances should see essentially the same storage. Are you sure the other instances are writing files that you can't see?

Comment: I know that the code emits log files to a "logs' subfolder sibling to the bin folder.  I see content in it -- and it's growing as we make API requests -- good correlation.

Are you saying that the "one" file I'm reading from (e.g. downloaded from Kudu/DebugConsole) is actually a file that contains unified content from all 6 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to access the log files on any of the other 5 instances?

Log files path is shared for all instances.
For more details, please refer to [Azure WebApp SandBox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#home-directory-access-dhome) and [Azure WebApp File Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-available-operating-system-functionality#file-access).

> Every Azure Web App has a home directory stored/backed by Azure Storage. This network share is where applications store their content. The home directory is shared among all instances so that all instances see the same directory

Comment: This is right.  What's also cool is that if I add an NLog `logger` that's connected to `System.Diagnostics.Trace` (e.g. `<target xsi:type="Trace"... />`) I can see my NLog logging output into the Log Stream.

I see log messages from all machines in the one log stream.

Answer (score 1):

We moved away from NLog for this exact reason.
Azure has native support for logging to Azure storage using native .Net Trace, you will have all the logs stored on storage per instance.

If you really want NLog to stay, you can configure the log names to include ${machinename} or processid